# ¿Como usar del cin.ignore() con espacios?

Tags: c++

mi programa consiste en lograr separar  una variables en dos variable , separando los números por medio de un espacio , me refiero que al momento de ingresar 23 45 una variable sea 23 y otra 45, lo he intentado con cin.ignore pero el 45 no lo toma correctamente no se porque, mi código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string datos;
    float I;
    float J;
    cout<<"ingrese  dos numeros separados por un espacio"<<endl;
    cin>>datos;
      std::stringstream valores(datos);
    valores >> I;
     valores.ignore(1, ' ');
     valores >> J;
     cout<<"su primer numero es "<<I <<" el otro numero es:"<<J<<endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El código funciona correctamente, lo que sucede es que no hace lo que esperas.

Tu problema está aquí:

```
cin>>datos;
```

Y el motivo es que la sobrecarga del operador `>>` con `std::string` se detiene cuando se encuentra un separador, que puede ser un salto de línea, **un espacio**, un tabulador o el final de la secuencia.

Para volcar toda la línea en el *stream*  tienes que usar `getline`:

```
std::getline(cin, datos);
```

Ahora bien, esto no es para nada necesario. La sobrecarga del operador `>>`  es capaz de descartar todos los separadores que se encuentren antes del valor pedido. Así, el siguiente ejemplo:

```
float i, j;
std::cin >> i >> j;
std::cout '#' << i << '#' << j << '#';
```

Será capaz de leer correctamente los dos números ante entradas bastante dispares, como puedes comprobar en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void Read2Floats(std::stringstream stream)
{
    float i, j;
    stream >> i >> j;

    std::cout << i << ' ' << j << '\n';
}

int main(int /* argc */, char** /* argv */) {
    std::string secuencias[] =
    {
      "12 34",                        // Un espacio
      "12           34",              // Varios espacios
      "12\n34",                       // Un salto de linea
      "12  \t  34",                   // Espacios y tabulador
      "12\n\n\t  \t\n\n   \n\t\t\n34" // Espacios, tabuladores y saltos de linea
    };

    for( std::string const& txt : secuencias )
    {
      Read2Floats(std::stringstream{txt});
    }
}
```

Puedes verlo funcionando [aqui](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IeA0IV3sqtInc0zP)